# How to retrieve inner array elements by matching key value in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have been trying to retrieve inner elements using ReactJs. If my input is country=NZ then I am expecting 4 results, it should consider the inner array also, however when I used jsonQuery it is not able to go to the inner array and fetching only 3 results, and it's not going inside friends1. Is there any way we can fetch inner array elements as well?

```
var result1 = jsonQuery('grouped_people[**][*country=NZ]', {data: data1}).value;
    console.log(result1);
    console.log("Array1");
    var data1 = {
        grouped_people: {
            'friends': [
                { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
                { name: 'Jane', country: 'US' },
                { name: 'Mike', country: 'AU' },
                { name: 'Mary', country: 'NZ' },
            ],
            'enemies': [
                { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
                {
                    'friends1': [
                        { name: 'Evil Steve', country: 'India' },
                        { name: 'Betty', country: 'NZ' },
                    ]
                }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to use only JSONQuery or vanilla is good also?

Comment: Am new to React, So i was using jsonQuery not sure of vanilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to optimise it as per your convenience.

```js
var data1 = {
    grouped_people: {
        'friends': [
            { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
            { name: 'Jane', country: 'US' },
            { name: 'Mike', country: 'AU' },
            { name: 'Mary', country: 'NZ' },
        ],
        'enemies': [
            { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
            {
                'friends1': [
                    { name: 'Evil Steve', country: 'India' },
                    { name: 'Betty', country: 'NZ' },
                ]
            }]
    }
}

const COUNTRY = "NZ";
const arr = [];

function getObject(obj) {
    if (obj.country) {
        if (obj.country === COUNTRY) {
            arr.push(obj);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
            obj[key].map(item => {
                getObject(item);
            });
        });
    }
}

getObject(data1.grouped_people);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used recursion to check (inside the `check` function ) whether the passed argument is an object. If so, then check for the key `country` and `name` and if they exist and the `country` value matches the `inp` then increment the `result1` by 1 and if the keys don't exist, call the function on the values of the keys.

if the type is not object, then, get every element of the new object(which can only be an array) and call the function over it.

```
let inp = 'NZ';
var result1 = 0;


console.log(result1);
console.log("Array1");
var data1 = {
    grouped_people: {
        'friends': [
            { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
            { name: 'Jane', country: 'US' },
            { name: 'Mike', country: 'AU' },
            { name: 'Mary', country: 'NZ' },
        ],
        'enemies': [
            { name: 'Steve', country: 'NZ' },
            {
                'friends1': [
                    { name: 'Evil Steve', country: 'India' },
                    { name: 'Betty', country: 'NZ' },
                ]
            }]
    }
}


function check(obj) {
  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    
    if(keys.includes('country') && keys.includes('name')) {
      if(obj['country'] == inp) {
        result1 += 1
      }
    }else {
      keys.map(key => {
        check(obj[key])
      })
    }
  }
  else {
    obj.map(ob => {
      check(ob)
    })
  }
  return result1;
}

let res = check(data1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using jsonQuery is not absolutely necessary, you can spread out the objects that you want into a dataset and format it using filter.

```
let resultSet = [...data1.grouped_people.friends, data1.grouped_people.enemies[0], ...data1.grouped_people.enemies[1].friends1]
resultSet.filter(e => e.country == 'NZ')
```